# Junit test falla pero muestra resultados idénticos en esperado y actual

Tags: java, eclipse, configuración, junit-5

Tengo un problema con unos Test Junit (v.5). Al lanzar los test hay algunos (no todos) que me fallan y me muestran que el valor esperado y el actual, son distintos, aunque comparándolos son idénticos. Colocando el visualizador de caracteres en blanco de eclipse me he encontrado con lo siguiente[hay un carácter blanco adicional]:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**No pidan código porque es código de producción de un proyecto.** El código esta bien porque otros compañeros lo ejecutan sin problemas, de lo que deduzco que debo tener alguna configuración cambiada en el eclipse de mi equipo.

¿Se les ocurre que pueda ser lo que provoque ese carácter blanco adicional que se genera?

**EDIT:**

- Este texto generado se encuentra en un archivo *.csv.
  Adicionalmente, hemos mirado un compañero y yo por si al hacer un merge entre ramas (que tuve que hacer hace dos días), pudiera haberse añadido este carácter adicional por error. Revisamos contra la rama que hay subida en el repositorio si había cambios con la rama que tenia yo, y con las rama que tenía mi compañero. El resultado fue que él, comparando su rama local y la rama subida; no veía el carácter adicional en ninguna de las dos. Al comparar yo mi rama local y la misma rama en el repositorio subida, yo si veía en las dos ramas el carácter adicional; por lo cual hemos deducido que debe a ver un cambio en alguna configuración de mi equipo, ya que no puede ser que la misma rama del repositorio, desde mi equipo aparezca el carácter blanco y en otro equipo no.

Estuve indagando por internet, encontré un dato curioso, la maquina virtual de java ejecutada desde Windows genera finales de linea con \r\n mientras que la de UNIX genera solo \n. Mi problema es que los ficheros que yo tengo descargados de la rama de trabajo de mi proyecto me aparecen en mi repositorio local con esta combinación "\r\n". Mientras que mis compañeros de trabajo al descargar la rama, ellos solo tienen \n.

Estos cambios solo afecta por lo que he podido observar a los ficheros dentro del proyecto, es decir; **ficheros creados o generados**, como **plantillas de .csv, .txt, .json, etc**; no a las clases del proyecto. Estuve probando a modificar las opciones que se encuentran en las preferencias del entorno de eclipse, que te permite modificar precisamente esta codificación. Trataré de detallar con fotos el proceso, aunque no ayuda a mi problema; por si alguien tiene problemas con estos finales de linea o codificaciones en un futuro ***(por editar)***. También hay una opción en el menú File (esto ya es el eclipse de mi casa no el de la empresa):

[image: menu File]

Como podéis observar, aquí se puede ver lo que mencionaba de los finales de linea y como para Windows se genera delimitadores finales \r\n (o sus respectivas distintas formas de representarlo como CR LF o los símbolos ASCII). Al seleccionarlo te realiza una refactorización de aquellos proyecto que hayas seleccionado previamente en la pestaña de **explorador de proyectos**. Pero no afecta a los ficheros la refactorización.

**[EDIT]ACERCAMIENTO AL PROBLEMA:**

Teniendo en cuenta que si un compañero y yo, ambos abrimos el repositorio de GIT y buscamos una misma rama subida del proyecto, y mostramos un fichero (en este caso un .csv) con la opción de visualizar caracteres blanco de eclipse; ambos vemos el mismo texto pero yo visualizo un carácter adicional (el \r) y él no... Y estamos hablando de algo subido a internet que visualizamos ambos al mismo tiempo... Hemos deducido que probablemente el fallo sea que GIT al descargar la rama realice una codificación propia que modifique el final de linea en los archivos tipo **fichero**. Precisamente la **configuración de GIT** es la única que no he revisado. Es más, desconocía que realizaba una codificación propia a la hora de descargar información de las ramas. Cuando realice las pruebas pertinentes actualizaré el post. Espero que sea ya la última actualización que haga.

Comment: Como estas generando el texto?, creo que sería importante tener más información, saludos.

Comment: @Jorgesys Se coge mediante un objeto stream y unos parametros fijados (constantes con la ubicación y el nombre del archivo) y se transforma mediante un método sobrecargado "toString" dentro de una clase de utilidades,  para ser agregado en un objeto InputStream. Vamos básicamente es eso, un stream pasado por un metodo toString, que muestra lo que ves arriba en la foto. El tema es que el resultado generado esta bien, el erroneo es el esperado, que no es mas que el fichero que ya tengo yo en mi proyecto. El fichero termina finales de linea con \r\n cuando deberia ser solo \n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUCIÓN:**

Como indiqué anteriormente, todo apuntaba a que era un problema de configuración del entorno, es este caso Git. Explico el tema:

- Un compañero del proyecto comentó que Git al bajar del repositorio de internet suele tener una configuración propia que genera los finales de linea propios, es decir; los CRLF (\r\n para los amigos) que en tantas configuraciones del entorno Eclipse los tiene y puedes configurar, GIT también tiene los suyos propios que se **superponen a los de eclipse**. Me puse a investigar y encontré este hilo:

[primer enlace](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=470643)

En este hilo te explica unos problemas con GIT y los CRLF de final de linea y alguien comenta sobre un hilo antiguo donde había ciertas referencias al tema y esta solucionado que es el siguiente hilo.

[segundo enlace](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=499615)

Aquí la persona explica que EGit genera finales erróneos de linea (lo que a mi me ocurría). Habla sobre la configuración de git y sobre el comando: "git config --local core.autocrlf true". Comenta que este problema le ocurre con los stash y los merges que precisamente es lo que yo había realizado antes de tener estos problemas. A si que me puse a investigar en eclipse y me encontré lo siguiente:

[image: configuración eclipse-GIT]

Mis compañeros de trabajo no tienen ningun archivo cargado de configuración de GIT. Como podéis observar la primera linea de core tiene el maldito autocrlf=true que genere los finales de linea con dos caracteres blancos \r\n haciendo que se diferenciara de lo esperado en los test Junit que terminan los finales de linea con solo \n.

¿Solución? Yo personalmente he vaciado el fichero de configuración.

[image: limpieza de configuración]

Por cierto necesitareis permisos de administración sino no te deja modificar el fichero, desde eclipse intente borrarlo pero por alguna razón me saltaba un error que me denegaba los cambios, a si que bloc de notas o Notepad++ es vuestro amigo. Posteriormente de eliminar la configuración descargué otra nueva rama a mi repositorio local y tachan, todos los ficheros .csv, .txt, .json, etc ya no tenían los finales de linea CRLF sino solo LF. Pruebas unitarias pasadas con éxito, los valores experados y generados coinciden.

**Espero que sirva para futuros programadores que se encuentren con estos problemas en su día a día en los proyectos de sus empresas.**

Answer (score 0):

en alguna oportunidad me paso eso, era por la configuración de charset del eclipse.

puedes probar 2 configuraciones.

1.- Sobre el proyectos propiedades --> recursos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2.- Configuración de eclipse, General --> Workspace

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola y gracias por la contestación. Ambas opciones que me muestras, las tengo exactamente como las tienes en tus imágenes subidas. ¿Se te ocurre alguna otra configuración?

Comment: Si  pruebas cambiadno en Text file encoding con UTF-8.

Comment: Buenas, ya lo he probado y lance las pruebas. Sigue generando ese símbolo adicional de final de celda.

Comment: Lo siento no haber ayudado, no se me ocurre ninguna otra solución, si dices que no es código.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, he actualizado el post, por si quieres hecharle un vistazo.

Comment: He leído, gracias por la información, no tenia idea que GIT hacia eso.